# .NET AWS SDK CreateInvalidation doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am using this code to invalidate CloudFront Files using ASP.NET AWS SDK.

```
public bool InvalidateFiles(string[] arrayofpaths)
{
    try
    {
        var client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonCloudFrontClient(MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, MY_AWS_SECRET_KEY);

        CreateInvalidationResponse r = client.CreateInvalidation(new CreateInvalidationRequest
        {
            DistributionId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DistributionId"],
            InvalidationBatch = new InvalidationBatch
            {
                Paths = new Paths
                {
                    Quantity = arrayofpaths.Length,
                    Items = arrayofpaths.ToList()
                },
                CallerReference = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()
            }
        });
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I supplied a path like "/images/1.jpg" but it seems that the invalidation doesn't take place. I've waited half and hour and used hard refresh and cleared the cache and the image is the same. I've changed the image to look different so I can notice the difference if invalidation has occurred.

In the console I see that the invalidation took place, because I have the ID and in the status I see 'completed', but again, nothing changed in the image.

My question is how can I check that the invalidation takes place and make it work, it seems that I am missing something.

Also, is there an option to  create is asynchronous, so I won't need to answer from Amazon.

Thanks.